# imagecreatefromjpeg breaks with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script (below) that uses imagecreatefromjpeg and it works. Then I add a couple of mysql statements, and it no longer works (I see the broken image icon).

How can I mix imagecreatefromjpeg and related with mysql queries. Thanks!

```
<?php
//Report any errors
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$user="root";
$password="pw";
$database="piwigo";

//Adding these two lines breaks the image:
  //mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
  //@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("sample.jpg");
// place code for saving the montage image as a file or outputting to the
// browser here.
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
imagejpeg($current_image);
imagedestroy($current_image);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Report any errors
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You reporting errors it it generates an output then image broke.

for example

mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);

must be

mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password);

Can you run below code for seeing are you getting any output except image

```
<?php
//Report any errors
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$user="root";
$password="pw";
$database="piwigo";

//Adding these two lines breaks the image:
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

// $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("sample.jpg");
// place code for saving the montage image as a file or outputting to the
// browser here.
// header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
// imagejpeg($current_image);
// imagedestroy($current_image);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Possible working code

```
<?php
// Don't Report any errors
error_reporting(0);

$user="root";
$password="pw";
$database="piwigo";

//Adding these two lines breaks the image:
mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password) or die("Unable to connect database");
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg("sample.jpg");
// place code for saving the montage image as a file or outputting to the
// browser here.
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
imagejpeg($current_image);
imagedestroy($current_image);

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: I think you may be exactly right!! I ran that and got:  Notice: Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost' in /var/www/photolog2/test.php on line 11

Comment: Yes, exactly right! I put localhost in quotes, and all works perfectly. Thanks again.